# F#: integer (%) integer - Is Calculated How?

Tags: math, recursion, f#, operators, modulus

So in my text book there is this example of a recursive function using f#

```
let rec gcd = function
| (0,n) -> n
| (m,n) -> gcd(n % m,m);;
```

with this function my text book gives the example by executing:

```
gcd(36,116);;
```

and since the m = 36 and not 0 then it ofcourse goes for the second clause like this:

```
gcd(116 % 36,36)
gcd(8,36)
gcd(36 % 8,8)
gcd(4,8)
gcd(8 % 4,4)
gcd(0,4) 
and now hits the first clause stating this entire thing is = 4.
```

What i don't get is this (%)percentage sign/operator or whatever it is called in this connection. for an instance i don't get how

```
116 % 36 = 8
```

I have turned this so many times in my head now and I can't figure how this can turn into 8?

I know this is probably a silly question for those of you who knows this but I would very much appreciate your help the same.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%` is a questionable version of *modulo*, which is the remainder of an integer division.

In the positive, you can think of `%` as the remainder of the division. See for example [Wikipedia on Euclidean Divison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division). Consider `9 % 4`: 4 fits into 9 twice. But two times four is only eight. Thus, there is a remainder of one.

If there are negative operands, `%` effectively ignores the signs to calculate the remainder and then uses the sign of the dividend as the sign of the result. This corresponds to the remainder of an integer division that rounds to zero, i.e. `-2 / 3 = 0`.

This is a mathematically unusual definition of division and remainder that has some bad properties. Normally, when calculating *modulo n*, adding or subtracting *n* on the input has no effect. Not so for this operator: `2 % 3` is not equal to `(2 - 3) % 3`.

I usually have the following defined to get useful remainders when there are negative operands:

```
/// Euclidean remainder, the proper modulo operation
let inline (%!) a b = (a % b + b) % b
```

So far, this operator was valid for all cases I have encountered where a modulo was needed, while the raw `%` repeatedly wasn't. For example:

- When filling rows and columns from a single index, you could calculate `rowNumber = index / nCols` and `colNumber = index % nCols`. But if `index` and `colNumber` can be negative, this mapping becomes invalid, while Euclidean division and remainder remain valid.
- If you want to normalize an angle to (0, 2pi), `angle %! (2. * System.Math.PI)` does the job, while the "normal" `%` might give you a headache.

Comment: okay i get it now!!! so because 36 can go into 116 3 times which adds to 108 then the remainder is 8! Thx for all the extra bonus info!

Comment: Your comments are not quite right regarding the behavior on negative arguments - only the sign of the dividend matters, not the sign of the divisor.

Comment: @kvb Thank you for the heads-up! I've corrected this. It's been too long since I've used the raw operator with negative inputs. But this makes sense: at least it's consistent with the `/` operator on signed integers. (Though I don't know of a case where that proved useful either.)

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
116 / 36 = 3
116 - (3*36) = 8
```

Comment: okay first of all 116/36 is not 3 it is 3.22222222... 3.222222...*36=116. 116-116=0

Comment: it is integer calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the % operator, known as the [modulo operator](http://%09%20en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) will divide a number by other and give the rest if it can't divide any longer. Usually, the first time you would use it to understand it would be if you want to see if a number is even or odd by doing something like this in f#

```
let firstUsageModulo = 55 %2 =0 // false because leaves 1 not 0
```

When it leaves 8 the first time means that it divided you 116 with 36 and the closest integer was 8 to give.

Answer (score 2):

Just to help you in future with similar problems: in IDEs such as Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio, if you hover the mouse cursor over an operator such as % you should get a tooltip, thus:

[Module operator tool tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w3rZ.png)

Even if you don't understand the tool tip directly, it'll give you something to google.